# using file() and preg_split() to create a table

Tags: php, file, split

let's say if I have a txt file and inside has info sample like this:

```
amy,anderson,aldergrove,archery,anchovies,110
bill,bonds,burnaby,bowling,beer,100
cameron,carson,cameroon,cars,candy,120
henry,henderson,harrison,helping,hamburgers,90
dorothy,dust,denmark,driving,drinks,80
ed,edmunson,edmonton,eating,eggs,77
fred,fredrickson,fernie,flying,fries,140
```

and I want to use the file() and preg_split() function to call it out and show as a table what's the easiest way to do it?
I know how to call it out using file() function but I'm not sure how to replace the , and make it look like a table.

http://et4891.site90.com/sample.jpg  <---this is a sample of how I want it to look like.

Below is what I did to call out the txt file.

```
<?php
$fileContentsArray = file("aaa.txt");
echo "<table>";
foreach($fileContentsArray as $one_persons_data)
{
    echo "<tr>$one_persons_data</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
?>
```

how should I modify this to make it look like the image I posted?

Thanks in adavance....

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: see how  $one_persons_data will return each line, so use preg_split on $one_persons_data which will give you array. use this array to output in each td (cell value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is preg_split required? Better to use explode in this case. Anyway:

```
<?php
$fileContentsArray = file("aaa.txt");
echo "<table>";
foreach($fileContentsArray as $one_persons_data)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  $splitted = preg_split('/,/', $one_persons_data);
  foreach ($splitted as $one) {
    echo "<td>$one</td>";
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: so does that mean the $one just means nothing and so it's just printing the <td></td>?

Comment: what I meant was so the preg_split makes the array splits by the comma and so $one becomes the single array inside the td tag.  Is that how it worked?

Comment: I think, I really don't understand your question. preg_split is splitting by comma (like explode, but here you are usign regular expressions) and make array of names in `$splitted`. Then, with foreach you will go through this array (assinging each element to $one) and write down the table cell (td). Does this work for you or not?

Comment: yes it works thanks.  Just trying to break it down how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php
$rows = file('data.txt');
echo '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach(explode(',',$row) as $field){
        echo '<td>';
        echo htnlentities($field);
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Hope this can help you.